# How to initialize object in different class?

Tags: c++

I'm learning c++ and I have problem with basics. 
How to init object in different class?

For example I have code:

```
class A {

  private:
     static int num;
     static string val;

  public:
    A(int n, string w) {        
       num = n;
       val = w;
   }
};
```

I want to create object A in class B, so I have try like this:

```
class B {
   private:
      A objA;
   public:
      B(int numA, string valA){
         objA = new A(numA, valA);
   }
};
```

Different ways(same constructor):

```
 public:
      B(A obA){
        objA = obA;
      }
```

or

```
 public:
      B(int numA, string valA){
         objA = A(numA, valA);
      }
```

Always I'm getting error: No default constructor for exist for class "A". I've read that default constructor is constructor without any arguments, but I give them, so why it is searching default?

Comment: What's a `LiczbaHeks`? Read about [constructor initializer lists](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list). And it doesn't look like you want `num` and `val` to be `static` data members.

Comment: Yes, you need an initializer list. And don't use `new` like that. And, you could always add a default constructor, but in this case you shouldn't need it.

Comment: I edit that "LiczbaHeks". It is from my code, I haven't seen this. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it the following way

```
class B {
   private:
      A objA;
   public:
      B(int numA, string valA) : objA( numA, valA ) {}
};
```

Comment: Thanks! I can only say.. that c++ is strange :D

Comment: @Ojmeny  Yes, it is not an intuitively clear language.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to learn C++ ... forget java.  C++ variables are values, not pointers in reference disguise.

`objA = new something` is an abomination, since `objA` is `A` and not `A*`.

What you need is just explicitly construct `objA` with proper parameter

```
class B {
   private:
      A objA;
   public:
      B(int numA, string valA) 
          :objA(numA, valA) 
      {
      }
   }
};
```

For more reference see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list

Comment: Thanks, it is a pity that I can't accept two answer. Vlad was first. Thanks any way!